# twilio download-invalid environment marker: python_version>="3.0"

Tags: python-2.7, twilio, packages.config

The picture shows invalid environment or Microsoft Visual c++ required and unable to find *vcvarsall.bat*.

[image: command prompt error screenshot]

Comment: What was the command that you ran that caused the first error in your screenshot? It looks like you were unable to install Python.

Comment: there are two cmd the one i used here was easy_install twilio

Comment: How did you install Python itself? Are you able to run the Python REPL by typing `python` or `python27` in your terminal?